# How to write value to input field

Tags: input, liferay, alloy-ui

I am getting element with

```
var nameEl = document.getElementById("<portlet:namespace />kategorijaName");
```

that is input field.How can i write some text in it ?

Comment: Question has nothing to do with AlloyUI, and very little to do with Liferay Portal, for that matter. This is about JavaScript and the DOM, and is likely a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

Since the question (at this time) is tagged [liferay](/questions/tagged/liferay) and [alloy-ui](/questions/tagged/alloy-ui), I am assuming an answer using/appropriate for those two tags would be beneficial

```
<aui:input id='textFieldId' name='textFieldName' label='My Text Field'></aui:input>

<script>
 AUI().use('node', function(A){
   A.one('#<portlet:namespace/>textFieldId').set('value', "A new input value"); 
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are using normal javascript then you can use below for setting a value in input text

```
document.getElementById("<portlet:namespace />kategorijaName").value = 'some value';
```

in case of Jquery you can use

```
 $("#<portlet:namespace />kategorijaName").val("some value");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using alloy-ui then you can set value like this

```
<aui:script>
    A.one('#<portlet:namespace />kategorijaName').set('value',kategorijaName);
</aui:script>
```

Answer (score -1):

`nameEl.value = "value you need"`